# AngularJS disable button based on form error

Tags: angularjs

Im having a form where user can save before submitting but save should be enabled only when field is !dirty or entered field is valid.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) which is useful in such cases.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myInput" />
    <input type="button" value="Save" ng-disabled="myForm.myInput.$dirty || myForm.myInput.$invalid" />
</form>
```